# How to make a condition on join table

Tags: sql, informix

If I have two tables like this :

**Location :**

```
loc_id loc_name
  1     xx
  2     yy
  3     zz
```

---

**Group :**

```
grp_id loc_id
  3      2
```

Now if i there's group i want only related locations if not i want the whole location table .

I do Query like this :

```
select distinct a.loc_id , a.loc_name 
from Location  a LEFT join Group b
on a.loc_id = b.loc_id 
where  (b.grp_id = 3 OR (b.group_id IS NULL))
```

But i get all the locations all the time cuz i use ORing

Comment: MS SQL Server and Informix are two different products. Which one are you using?

Comment: @jarlh :i use `informix`

Comment: of course you get all the locations : first there is that left join, then your b.grp_id is null ... what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: @Pras If  there group related to locations i want only these locations if there'snot i want all locations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT loc_id, loc_name
FROM Location l
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM Group g
              WHERE l.loc_id = g.loc_id AND
                    g.grp_id = 3)

UNION ALL

SELECT loc_id, loc_name
FROM Location 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM Location l
                  JOIN GROUP g ON l.loc_id = g.loc_id
                  WHERE g.grp_id = 3)
```

If there are matching `Location` records for the `Group` specified, then these records will be returned by the first query of the `UNION ALL` operation. The second query will return an empty set in this case.

If there are *no* matching records, then the first query will return an empty set, whereas the second query will return *all* records of table `Location`.

Comment: Brilliant ,just amazing :D

Comment: In the first query you can join the tables, and on the second on the NOT exists there is no need to join, you just want to know if there is a grp_id. SELECT  l.loc_id, l.loc_name
FROM  location l
   JOIN group AS g ON (l.loc_id = g.loc_id)
WHERE  g.grp_id = 3
UNION ALL
SELECT  l.loc_id, l.loc_name
FROM  location l 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT  1 
   FROM  group g 
   WHERE  g.grp_id = 3
  )